# I need a hint - is it possible to push a msg to iphones that are only in some particular area (geo-based notifications)?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, geolocation, apple-push-notifications

I'm not sure if it is possible or not, I just need some hints here - let's assume a scenario like this:

- users install my app on their iphones
- one day I put a gps coordinates on my webservice and some small info
- this information + coordinates are pushed to the iphones around (e.g. +/- 10 miles) to the coordinations I gave at the beginning
- all users in this area (+/- 10 miles) gets a push notification and can open my app
- on some other time I repeat the scenario but with different coordinates (so that it equals different target group)

Is that possible? I was thinking about [Deferring location updates while app is in the background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW13) but I'm not sure if that can also work with different locations each time given by webservice...

The other solution that I thought about was to push the message and coordinates to all users of my app, but display it only within the ones with matching gps coordinates - but I guess it's not possible since when I do a push message - everyone will see it even before calculating their gps coordinates, is that correct?

Sorry if that's a terrible question, I'm just starting with iOS now...
Thanks for any hints guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcGIS has some good tools for this, that is, if you're willing to pay for access to their APIs. They also have a full development team on standby that will develop the app for you. Partnering with ArcGIS is overkill for this situation though.

What I would suggest is to keep a database of coordinates, the actual notification, and the radius on an app management site like: [socket.io](http://socket.io/) and have it push any new data to the client apps, have the client apps check their GPS location against the database one...do some simple math to decide if the client device is inside the raduis, if so, display the pushed notification...and there you go.

Comment: Thanks for that, I will take a closer look at socket.io! However, one question - you wrote that I should keep a database of coordinates on an app management site and push any new coordinates to the client app. That's a clever solution, BUT - if any user of my app is not in a desired range - will he still see a push notification on his phone? Or will it be in the background and he will see it only in case when he is in a specified (desired) geographic area?

Comment: The data you include in the database would be the coordinates, the actual notification, and the radius. It would push all of this to the client, and the client would decide, using math, if it was within the radius...then display the notification

Comment: Added clarification to the answer ^

Comment: thanks for your patience! :) So I understand all of this, there's only one question left - when the server pushes the notification with coordinates and radius to the client apps - will they always notify the user that the push message was received or only when they match the coordinates? In other words -is it possible to send a 'hidden/silent' push msg and invoke my app only when everything matches?

Comment: That is all up to whoever codes the client. I would assume that you don't want the notification shown unless they're within radius that can be done very easily. Yes the notification would be downloaded by the client device, but as soon as the device "realizes" it is not within the radius it can delete the downloaded data or just ignore it.

Comment: that is exactly what I wanted to read :D thank you very much!